# How to convert JspxIncludePathReferenceProvider for IntelliJ IDEA 8

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I wrote an IntelliJ IDEA plugin for version 7.0 that uses JspxIncludePathReferenceProvider to allow autocomplete in a custom JSP tag (e.g. dsp:include src="/path/to/file.jsp").

The new version 8 of IntelliJ has changed the API for the Reference providers and I can't figure out how to convert this plugin for the new API.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JspReferenceProvidersUtil.PATH_REFERENCES_PROVIDER